# Uniqueness of ODE solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ locally Lipschitz. Does the initial value problem $y'=f(y)$, $y(0)=y_0$ have a unique solution on $\mathbb{R}$ if $f\left(\frac{y_0}{2}\right)=f(2 y_0)=0$?

From Picard Lindelöf I know the existence and uniqueness of a solution on every open intervall around $0$. I don't know how to use the conditions on $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem that could prevent global existence of the solution would be that $y$ goes off to $\pm \infty$ at some finite value of the independent variable.  But in your case, what would happen as $y$ approached $y_0/2$ or $2 y_0$?

Comment: I only know that the derivative of $y$ is $0$ at those points. Is y bounded by $y_0/2$ and $2y_0$? I don't see why.

Comment: I guess I don't know how to use that x is a independent variable.

Comment: Ok, I got it. The integral curves cannot cross each other and so the solution is indeed bounded by $y_0/2$ and $y_0$